# Binding to value in parent page from in usercontrol in listview datatemplate in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, data-binding, binding, datatemplate

I have a ViewCharacter page that has a View Model (CharacterViewModel) as its DataContext, in that CharacterViewModel I have an ObservableCollection of WeaponViewModel that a ListBox is using as an ItemSource. The ListBox's DataTemplate contains a UserControl that is designed for the WeaponViewModels in the parent page's View Model's ObservableCollection. I need to bind a CommandParameter of a button in the UserControl to a property on the Parent page's view model (CharacterViewModel). I've tried using `{Binding DataContext.TargetProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}` with no success and am at a loss of what to do without outright breaking all MVVM patterns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Phone 7 lacks a relative source binding. I have created a Silverlight implementation here:

http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2009/02/relativesource-binding-in-silverlight/

But for WP7, where performance is critical, I would avoid using it!

I would instead recommend making the relationship between `CharacterViewModel` and `WeaponViewModel` bi-directional. In other words, add a `Parent` property to `WeaponViewModel` which will be a reference to the owning `CharacterViewModel`. You can then bind to properties on `CharacterViewModel` via this property.

Comment: While it's disappointing that I have to resort to alternative methods to get to the data I need, your method makes sense. Never really considered that instead of trying to access the parent of the view, access the parent of the viewModel.